# Best practice for house floorplan scene changing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a house floorplan in scene A. Players can click a room on the plan and go into that specific room. What they find there will be an image of that specific room and some character stats about that rooms current occupant (not the player).

At the moment, I handle this with a set of public variables in a gameobject instance "target room 1" "current occupant Henry" and use those to build a single scene.

I was wondering how you would go about this. Is there a better way? Is it better to have one scene for each room? How would you get players to a situation that they see the room and the specific occupant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that depends a lot on the game you have and how would it be easier for you (and/or your team) to manage it.

You can make each room a different scene and just reference it and load it on click. That would work best if each room is complex. Programming wise - If it has whole set of information and states to take care of it would be harder to manage those systems for every room in a single scene. Design-wise - if it's a complex room with lots of object  making it a different scene would be easier and cleaner for you to work with. Drawback is, well the frequent scene loading. That also means that if you need some state to persist across different rooms you'd have to figure out how to do it across scenes.

You can make each room a game object and just enable it and move it in the field of view of the camera. That would work best for simple scenarios where there isn't too much complexity about the functionality and design of every room. Also you get the benefit that you can easily just have something like Room Manager that can make interaction between rooms easier.

You can make a single room object in the scene and populate it with data at runtime  when you select a room from the plan. That is a very good option if all the rooms are sort of homogeneous and just have some variables that need to be changed - perhaps an image, a name or certain prefab that has to be instantiated. A nice structure for that would be to have perhaps a RoomData scriptable object with all the data in it and a RoomObject prefab that you put in the scene. The RoomObject will take in the RoomData and display it. That way you can quickly make different rooms by just creating new data files. You can also make different types of prefabs that handle the data a little diffrenetly - perhaps if you want a BedroomObject that has a different layout or something like that